# EF Core RC2 FinaI Issue: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

After replacing EF Core rc 1 with EF Core rc 2 final, We are getting an invalid operation exception when calling GetService() method bellow. The goal here is to get the corresponding DbContext from any given DbSet:

```
public static ObservableCollection<TEntity> Local<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> set)
            where TEntity : class
{
            var context = set.GetService<DbContext>();
            ...
}
```

The exception full message:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A
>   provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring
>   method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider.
>   If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
>   accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to
>   the base constructor for DbContext.

We effectively are setting the database provider in OnConfiguring:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(builder);
    var connStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    connStringBuilder.UserID = "MyUserID";
    ...         
    builder.UseSqlServer(connStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
}
```

So it seems that the issue comes from the method GetService() not resolving the correct DbContext instance for the given DbSet?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reporting this issue with the EF team, they bring the following workaround:

```
public static ObservableCollection<TEntity> Local<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> set)
            where TEntity : class
{
    var context = set.GetService<ICurrentDbContext>().Context;            
    ...
}
```

Note the use of the interface *ICurrentDbContext* instead of *DbContext*.

Details [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5385)